# Qual o objetivo de usar "else" junto com try/except em Python?

Tags: python

Em Python, qual a vantagem de usar `else` em um bloco `try/catch`?

Se no neste exemplo abaixo:

```
try:
    f = open('texto.txt', 'r')
except IOError:
    print('O arquivo não existe!')
else:
    print(f.read())
    f.close()
```

Eu fizer desta outra forma, sem o `else`:

```
try:
    f = open('texto.txt', 'r')
    print(f.read())
    f.close()
except IOError:
    print('O arquivo não existe!')
```

Não dá na mesma?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para **este** exemplo pode não fazer diferença, mas para outros sim.

A ideia é sempre manter o menor bloco de código possível dentro do `try` que você deseja capturar a exceção. Por exemplo, imagine que você irá fazer três chamadas de funções:

```
try:
    funcao1()
    funcao2()
    funcao3()
except ValueError as error:
    print(error)
```

Se somente uma das funções lançar a exceção, ok, você não terá muitos problemas. Mas e se as três puderem lançar a mesma exceção `ValueError`? Como você saberá qual foi a função que a lançou? Você pode analisar o *traceback* para isso, mas é um trabalho desnecessário. Se a sua ação para quando uma exceção é lançada é a mesma, independente de qual função que lançou, beleza, você também não terá problemas com essa forma, mas se precisará tomar rumos distintos dependendo de quem lançou a exceção ficará complicado.

```
try:
    data = request_api_data()
    insert_in_database(data)
    send_mail()
except RuntimeError as error:
    print(error)
```

Por exemplo, você acessa uma API externa, pega os dados desejados, salva no banco de dados e envia uma notificação por e-mail. A título de exemplo as três funções lançam a exceção `RuntimeError` em caso de falha. Provavelmente você irá querer tomar providências diferentes caso seja a API que não está respondendo, tal como tentar novamente mais tarde; se o problema está na conexão com o banco provavelmente você gostaria de alertar os responsáveis e se der erro no envio de e-mail quem sabe você até poderia ignorar. No mesmo `except` como fazer isso? Então:

```
try:
    data = request_api_data()
except RuntimeError as error:
    retry('5 minutes')
else:
    try:
        insert_in_database(data)
    except RuntimeError as error:
        notify_support()
    else:
        try:
            send_mail()
        except RuntimeError as error:
            pass
```

Obviamente que neste caso, por ser um exemplo bastante aleatório, eu acabei aninhando muitas coisas, mas em um caso real você poderia simplificar conforme suas necessidades.

Em resumo, dentro do bloco `try` fica apenas a parte do código que você deseja tratar a exceção. Aquilo que pode lançar outra exceção que não será tratada deve ficar fora do bloco - usando o `else` caso a exceção não redirecione a aplicação para outro ponto do código ou fora do bloco `try/except` caso seja seguro.

Answer (score 6):

**Cláusula `else` a incompreendida e desprezada.**

Sempre quando pensamos em `else` associamos imediatamente com blocos `if`, como diz Luciano Ramalho em seu livro [Python fluente](https://www.amazon.com.br/Fluent-Python-Luciano-Ramalho/dp/1491946008?tag=goog0ef-20&smid=A1ZZFT5FULY4LN&ascsubtag=go_1494986073_58431735035_285514469186_pla-485032980911_c_), "A clausula `else` é um recurso subutilizado da linguagem, ela pode ser utilizada não só em comandos `if`, mas também em comandos `for`, `while` e `try`."

**Try:**

No caso da utilização de `else` em `try/except`, o bloco `else` só será executado se nenhuma exceção for levantada no bloco `try`, segundo a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement), exceções levantadas no bloco `else` não serão tratadas pelas clausulas `execpt` anteriores.

Um exemplo da utilização em bloco try:

```
try: 
    chamada_arriscada()
    pos_chamada()
except OSError:
    log('OSError...')
```

Tecnicamente falando o codigo acima não está errado, mas colocar `pos_chamada()` dentro do bloco `try` sem um bom motivo torna o código dúbio e/ou obscuro, por questão de clareza um bloco `try` deve conter apenas comandos que possam gerar exceções, dessa forma, é melhor fazer:

```
try: 
    chamada_arriscada()
except OSError:
    log('OSError...')
else:
    pos_chamada()
```

**For:**

O bloco `else` só será executado após o término do laço `for`, se houver uma interrupção por um `break`, por exemplo, o bloco após o `else`não será executado.

**While:**

Novamente o bloco `else`não será executado se o while for interrompido pro um `break`, isto é, `else`só será excetuado se o `while` terminar em função da condição ter se tornado falsa.

Se em qualquer um dos casos uma exceção ou um comando `return`, `break` ou `continue` ocorrer e fizer o controle sair do loop principal, a clausula `else`será ignorada.

Citando novamente o Luciano Ramalho, concordo com ele quando diz:

> Acho `else`uma péssima escolha de palavra reservada em todos os casos, exceto com `if`. Ela implica uma alternativa excludente, como "execute este laço; caso contrário, faça aquilo", mas a semantica de `else` em laços é o oposto disso: "execute esse laço, então faça aquilo". Isso sugere que `then` seria uma palavra reservada melhor - e também faria sentido no contexto de **try**: "Tente isso e então faça aquilo". Contudo acrescentar novas palavras reservadas pode quebrar muito código existente, e Guido evita isso como se fosse uma praga.

Nota: Guido refere-se a [Guido van Rossum](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guido_van_Rossum), o criador da linguagem.

> Editada: Atendendo ao comentário do @Guilherme Nascimento, adicionei exemplos e explicação para os laços `for` e `while`. [TL;DR](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/clausula-else)

**Preambulo para exemplos com `for` e `while`:**

É dificil dar um exemplo específico ou "real", por que seria preciso explicar o contexto, então criei um exemplo genérico que pode parecer meio "nonsense", mas é baseado em um caso real. Vamos supor que recebemos uma lista de uma operação qualquer que usaremos mais a frente em nosso código, mas antes precisamos normaliza-la (fazer com que cada item fique entre 0 e 1) caso o número 7 **não** apareça nessa lista. Para isso, vamos, antes, criar a função de normalização:

```
def normalize(lst):
    sum_lst = sum(lst)
    norm_lst = []
    for n in range(len(lst)):
        norm_lst.append(lst[n]/sum_lst)
    return norm_lst
```

Agora vamos criar 2 listas uma em que aparece o numero 7 (nesse caso a função normalize **não** deverá ser chamada) e outro em que não aparece.

```
lista1, lista2 = [1,2,3,6,7,9], [1,3,5,9,44,55]
```

**Exemplo com a utilização de `for`:**

Para ficar mais prático, vamos definir uma função que recebe a lista e checa se há a presenca do elemento que evita a chamada à normalização, no caso o número 7 e em seguida testamos com as duas listas criadas anteriormente:

```
# Loop for
def test_for(lst):
    for item in lst:
        if item == 7:
            break
    else:
        return normalize(lst)
    return lst
```

Testando com a lista1:

```
test_for(lista1)
```

Saída:

```
[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9]
```

Note que como o loop principal foi interrompido por `break` (a `lista1` tem o número 7), a função de normalização não foi chamada.

Testando com a lista2:

```
test_for(lista2)
```

Saída:

```
[0.008547008547008548,
 0.02564102564102564,
 0.042735042735042736,
 0.07692307692307693,
 0.37606837606837606,
 0.4700854700854701]
```

Agora como a `lista2` não contém o número 7, o loop `for` foi executado até o fim, testando todos os elementos da lista e **então** a função de normalização foi chamada no bloco após o `else`.

**Exemplo com a utilização do laço `while`:**

Assim como fizemos com `for`, vamos definir uma função para testar o laço `while`:

```
# Loop While
def test_while(lst):
    n = 1
    while n <= len(lst)-1:
        if lst[n-1] == 7:
            break
        n+=1
    else:
        return normalize(lst)
    return lst
```

Testando com a `lista1`

```
test_while(lista1)
```

Saída:

```
[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9]
```

Novamente, como essa lista contém o número 7, a função de normalização não foi chamada, pois o laço principal (`while`) não foi executado até fim, foi interrompido pelo `break` no penúltimo elemento da lista.

Testando com a `lista2`:

```
test_while(lista2)
```

Saída:

```
[0.008547008547008548,
 0.02564102564102564,
 0.042735042735042736,
 0.07692307692307693,
 0.37606837606837606,
 0.4700854700854701]
```

Nesse caso o loop while foi executado até o final, isto é, até que a variável `n` não atendesse a condição do loop `n` menor ou igual ao numero de elementos da lista, ou seja, todos os elementos da lista foram testados, **então** a cláusula `else` foi executada.

[Veja funcionando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/clausula-else)

Comment: A explicação sobre for e while ficou sensacional, já tem meu +1, gostaria de pedir que adicione exemplos com comentários de explicação da "saída", enriqueceria e facilitaria o entendimento de quem esta começado.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Criei um exemplo ficticio, os exemplos "reais" que tenho ficaria sem sentido fora do contexto, mas acho que consegui elucidar um pouco mais.